# Problems installing Ubuntu / Kubuntu 18.04 on new build computer

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, radeon

I build a new computer with Gigabyte B360n wifi motherboard (Bios F4), a I7 8700 and a Sapphire Radeon RX 590. Linux Mint KDE 18 Serena booted perfectly,
and installed without producing errors in uefi mode with activated csm in bios.
(K)Ubuntu did not, even with all combinations of secure boot / legacy / uefi
activated/deactivated. with csm on and in uefi the only exception it threw was

```
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db    list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

All the other combinations ended up with a black screen, no live boot even after 15 Minutes.

Now two questions:

Phoronix blogged that driver support for the gpu would be added to kernel 4.20.
Is it sufficient just to update the kernel in Mint in order to get the gpu running with full performance or is it better to install ubuntu and use amd's driver for ubuntu 18?

If ubuntu installation is necessary, how can I manage to boot it?

---

Edit:

I just updated the linux mint kernel to 4.15 and on reboot encountered the same problem. Black screen an a timespan of two seconds in which the GPU fans run high, then silence.
So, the problem is linked to the kernel, isn't it?
For Ubuntu 18.04 the kernel will be 4.15 < I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I removed the GPU from the computer and after that I was able to boot Ubuntu 18.04 with Kernel 4.18. After updating to Kernel 4.20 and inofficial Mesa 19 The Graphics card was recognized but a fatal error occured during gpu initialization.

Installing the amdpgu proprietary driver (compatible with ubuntu 18.04) corrupted the system completely. I could'nt even boot again.
I will return this GPU to the seller.

Edit:
I just found this article:
https://www.pcgamesn.com/amd-rx-590-linux-failure-to-launch-workaround
Seems other people have this problem too.
I switched to rtx 2060 now, meaning 35 % more performance and no trouble with driver version 415.